# status or history showing instead of review disabling

Tags: feature-request, review

When a reviewer reviews 20 items, the review link disabled and moves down.

I think this should improved like this:

- Review link don't become disable.
- By clicking the link instead of -default tab- `review` tab; `stats` tab displayed.
- For showing users that this review is *on hold* use something like adding a `[On hold]` text add the end of the review name.
- On hold reviews moves down, but upper than invalid reviews.

Because of:

- Users only have a link to `review` at all page -I know that users can add bookmarks-.
- Making a difference between invalid reviews -because of privileges- and on-hold reviews.
- This make users to visits their ranks after gaining limitation and many other information in `stats` and `history` tabs are available.